# How to increase thermal shock resistance of the electronics components?

Tags: pcb, components, thermal, materials

How to increase thermal shock resistance of the electronics components assembled on the PCB? Is there any material (or method) for increasing the thermal shock resistance of components?

Best Regards,

EDIT1 : Correct term is Thermal Shock Resistance. (Credit : comments)
EDIT2 : Procedure is seen below. T1 is -40 celcius, and T2 is 85 celcius. Is this enough to be able to find a solution ?
EDIT3 : This is an interview question comes to me for a position about the electronic design. So I have not conducted a test for observing a specific electronics component and interface fault.

[image]

Comment: Can you quantify the thermal shock?

Comment: What temperature range? out of the Bessemer furnace and into liquid Nitrogen?

Comment: You NEED to define a temperature range or end points for us. What is the 'HOT' temperature and for how long? What is the 'cold' temperature and for how long?

Comment: "Thermal Shock Strength" is not a term I have heard before, and is a bit confusing. "Thermal Shock Resistance" is a term I have heard many times.

Comment: Thermal shock usually means high dT/dt, not just high temperature. It can be a low temperature as well.

Comment: You need a rate of change of temperature such as x celcius per minute. I dont know. We can take a 'sudden changes' like an 10 celcius within one minute. Range could be taken [-40, 100]  celcius ambient. I dont know detailed test procedures.

Comment: Why don't you know the rate of change? Are you just "fishing" with a non-specific question?

Comment: Because I dont know mil-std 810 thermal shock requirements. So I could not specify a rate of change. Just I see it is 10 celcius within a minute in google now.

Comment: @doner_t MIL-STD-810G is freely available. Read METHOD 503.5, section 2.3. Levels depend entirely on application and environment. You need to determine that for your system/equipment. http://everyspec.com/MIL-STD/MIL-STD-0800-0899/MIL-STD-810G_12306/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*( added after your edit 3.)

This sort of question expects the person to show awareness of root cause failure analysis as the first reply.  So the solution starts with identifying the problem root cause.
It usually pinpoints to a design or process weakness. Then apply appropriate design or process improvement(s).  (ie. Forensic countermeasures.) For Automotive or Military market it is related to HALT/HASS reliability testing. So the question shows your experience level ranging from 0 to 10.*

1) Thermal insulation compound ( generally anything plastic, silicone, conformal coating )

Unfortunately, improving Thermal shock resistance also increases thermal resistance and temperature rise in the substrate of heat generating parts.

Solutions require measurable specs.  Where are yours?

**Background**
Shock is defined as anything > 10'C or >10'C/minute.  It is intended to stress the interface of components which may expand by different coefficents (CTE) and different rates of expansion thereby testing its marginal strength with high stress.

### Details of Question

The thermal test shows the test in the middle must be done in < 1 minute from T1 to T2 or the reverse which computes to a slope > 125'C/minute.

If something breaks that is a result of a design or process flaw then the solution then the flaw must be identified, fixed and verified.

This test can be performed both operating and non-operating and the failures may be permanent or temporary.

Forensic debug and electro-mechanical Engineering skills must be learned to identify the flaw and then determine how to prevent  the flaw by re-design of the process or product.  **( We cannot decide which or suggest how to fix it  without seeing the failure.)**

Comment: Dear @Tony Stewart. EE since, I have editted questions that specs are given.

Comment: Thankyou @doner_t  Can you explain the faulty test result, what failed?and was it examined for physical root cause or which interface broke?

Comment: Dear @Tony Stewart. EE since '75, this is an interview question comes to me for position about the electronic design. But especially mentioned that how to increase thermal shock resistance of "SDRAM Memory like DDR3 chips". So, I have not conducted a specific test for a certain components or interface. But I have learnt that protection to the thermal shock depends on the component itself and interface.

Comment: It usually pinpoints to a design or process weakness.  Forensic countermeasures.  Related to HALT/HASS reliability testing. So it shows your experience level.  Not ability to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If the shock is caused externally- isolate. If internally- dissipate. So it's either high thermal resistance to environment or low, depends.

Comment: Did you mean dissi**p**ate?

Comment: Yes. I am typing on the phone